# Startup of IHostedService's in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core

1. Are container-registered IHostedService's started in parallell or sequential?
2. Are the startups waited on before accepting incoming request?
3. If the startup crashes, how can this be detected? It seem to swallow this.
4. If a service crashes during operation, can it be configured to restart automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I can answer most of these myself after some research:

1. They seem to start in the sequence they are registered, and not in parallell.
2. StartAsync is not waited on and requests are handled before StartAsync is completed (which can be mitigated with a custom middleware).
3. If StartAsync crashes it will go unnoticed (which I read somewhere should apparently be fixed for a future release).
4. If crashing during operation this will also go unnoticed and I haven't found a way to restart them with config, though it should be fairly easy to make a custom manager to restart them.